# How to capitalize first and last letters of each word in a Python string?

Tags: python

I want to write a python function so that the first and last letters of the words in a string will be capitalized. The string contains lower case letters and spaces.
I was thinking of doing something like:

```
def capitalize(s):
     s.title()
     s[len(s) - 1].upper()
     return s
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

For example, the string "i like cats" should become "I LikE CatS"

Comment: Python strings are immutable. You have to reassign it: `s = s.title()`.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian How would `startswith` and `endswith` help here?

Answer (score 4):

```
def capitalize(s):
     s, result = s.title(), ""
     for word in s.split():
        result += word[:-1] + word[-1].upper() + " "
     return result[:-1]     #To remove the last trailing space.

print capitalize("i like cats")
```

**Output**

```
I LikE CatS
```

Apply `title()` to the whole string, then for each word in the string capitalize the last character and the append them back together.

Comment: Nice! however, how would you remove the final space after the string?

Comment: @perry Please check the answer now. We can do `return result[:-1]` instead of `return result` to get rid off the last space.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice one-liner. (for you golfers :P)

```
capEnds = lambda s: (s[:1].upper() + s[1:-1] + s[-1:].upper())[:len(s)]
```

It demonstrates another way to get around the problems when the input is 0 or 1 characters.

It can easily be applied to a string to capitalize the individual words:

```
' '.join(map(capEnds, 'I like cats'.split(' '))) 
'I LikE CatS'
```

Comment: @jterrace whether or not it works depends on how you look at the two different questions OP asked. His function and his title both indicate he wants to capitalize the first and last letters of *a string*. His example, which he only added later, indicates he wants to capitalize the first and last letters of *each word* in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try using slicing.

```
def upup(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        return s.upper()
    return ''.join((s[0:-1].title(),s[-1].upper())))
```

Edit: since the OP edited in that he now needs this for *every word* in a string...

```
' '.join(upup(s) for s in 'i like cats'.split())
Out[7]: 'I LikE CatS'
```

Comment: That won't quite work, though it will in most cases.. (hint ;^)

Comment: @DSM I don't follow, unless you're talking about 0-length strings?

Comment: @DSM haha, okay you got me.  Edited.

Comment: Since strings are immutable, using a buffer or ''.join(list) is certainly faster for joining a string split into many parts. In this case, with only three parts, I'm not sure `''.join` is doing you any favors.

Answer (score 1):

My take on a fun one-liner:

```
def cap_both(phrase):
    return ' '.join(map(lambda s: s[:-1]+s[-1].upper(), phrase.title().split()))
```

Demo:

```
>>> cap_both('i like cats')
'I LikE CatS'
>>> cap_both('a')
'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it's what we will do:

1. Break the sentence into words
2. Apply a function that capitalizes first and last word of a word
3. Regroup the sentences
4. Write the function in (2)

So:

0)

> > > words = "welcome to the jungle!"

1)

```
>>> words= words.split()
```

2)

```
>>> words = [capitalize(x) for x in words]
```

3)

```
>>> words = " ".join(words)
```

4)

```
def capitalize(word):
    return word[0].capitalize() + word[1:-1] + word[-1].capitalize()
```

Comment: Your `capitalize` function won't handle one-letter words.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple and easy to understand piece of code,

```
st = 'this is a test string'

def Capitalize(st):    
    for word in st.split():
        newstring = ''
        if len(word) > 1:
            word = word[0].upper() + word[1:-1] + word[-1].upper()
        else:
            word = word[0].upper()
        newstring += word
        print(word)
```

And than call the function as below,

```
Capitalize(st)
```

Answer (score 0):

A really old post but another fun one liner using list comprehension:

```
cap = lambda st: (" ").join([x.title().replace(x[-1], x[-1].upper()) for x in st.split()])

>>> cap("I like cats")
'I LikE CatS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!

```
def capitalize(s):
        return ' '.join(map(lambda s: s[:-1]+s[-1].upper(),
                            s.title().split()))

st = "i like cats"
print("String before:", st)
print("String after:", capitalize(st))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
n=input("Enter the str: ")

for i in n.split():

    print(i[0].upper() +i[1:-1] +i[-1].upper(),end=' ')
```

Comment: This does not add anything to existing answers